# Spring Webflux - Formatting JSON response correctly

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am trying to achieve an output that looks like this

```
{
    "shipment": {
        "111": [
            "ITEM1",
            "ITEM2",
            "ITEM3"
        ],
        "222": [
            "ITEM4",
            "ITEM5",
            "ITEM6"
        ]
    }
}
```

In a traditional way of coding, I believe the above can be achieved by :

```
Map<String, List<String>> shipment = new HashMap<>();
shipment.put("111", Arrays.asList("ITEM1", "ITEM2", "ITEM3"));
shipment.put("222", Arrays.asList("ITEM4", "ITEM5", "ITEM6"));
Map.of("shipment", shipment);
```

However, with my current Spring Webflux code

```
public Flux<Map<String, List<String>>> getShipment(List<String> shipmentOrderNumbers) {
    final String apiUrl = "/some-path";
    final String queryParam = "some-query-param";
    
    ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>> expectedType = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>() {};
    
    Flux<Map<String, List<String>>> values = Flux.fromIterable(shipmentOrderNumbers)
        .flatMap(orderNo -> this.client.get()
        .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path(apiUrl).queryParam(queryParam, orderNo).build()).retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(expectedType).map(product -> Map.of(orderNo, product)));
    
    return values;
}
```

I get a totally different JSON structure

```
[
    {
        "111": [
            "ITEM1",
            "ITEM2",
            "ITEM3"
        ]
    },
    {
        "222": [
            "ITEM4",
            "ITEM5",
            "ITEM6"
        ]
    }
]
```

The key "shipment" containing the arrays is missing. How can I achieve the one with key "shipment"

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you should build and return `Mono<Map<Map<String, List<String>>>>`

You're getting an array because you're returing `Flux` which means "many elements"

But since`Mono<Map<Map<String, List<String>>>>` is not readable, it is better to create a dto class like this:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Response {

    @JsonUnwrapped
    private Shipment shipment;

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public static class Shipment {

        private Map<String, List<String>> shipment;
    }
}
```

Then you write your controller like this:

```
public Mono<Response> getShipment(List<String> shipmentOrderNumbers) {
    final String apiUrl = "/some-path";
    final String queryParam = "some-query-param";

    ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>> expectedType = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>() {};

    return Flux.fromIterable(shipmentOrderNumbers)
            .flatMap(orderNo -> this.client.get()
                    .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path(apiUrl).queryParam(queryParam, orderNo).build())
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(expectedType)
                    .map(product -> Pair.of(orderNo, product)) // map list to pair of orderNo vs list
            )
            .collectMap(Pair::getFirst, Pair::getSecond) // collect pairs keys and values to map
            .map(Response.Shipment::new) 
            .map(Response::new);
}
```

Note: I'm using here `Pair` class to wrap key-value instead of using single-valued hashmap. This class is from `org.springframework.data.util` package

Answer (score 0):

Create a class named let's say **Response.java** create one variable in it named **shipment**.It will look like this:

```
public class Response {
    public Response() {}
    public Response(Flux<Map<String, List<String>>> shipment) {
        this.shipment = shipment;
    }
    
    private Flux<Map<String, List<String>>> shipment;

    public void setShipment(Flux<Map<String, List<String>>> shipment) {
        this.shipment = shipment;
    }

    public Flux<Map<String, List<String>>> getShipment(){
        return shipment;
    }
}
```

After that add following line in your code.

```
Response resp = new Response(values);
return resp;
```

This will give you the exact JSON you are looking for.